# Why multiply by volume when integrating over final momenta in scattering amplitude calculations?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, fermis-golden-rule

I am learning about calculating decay rates from quantum field theory amplitudes from [David Tong's lecture notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/three.pdf) (page 74 in the notes, 24 in document). However, I have some doubts:

1. When he says *the ﬁrst is to integrate over all possible momenta of the ﬁnal particles,* he uses the measure $V \int \frac{d^{3} p_{i}}{(2 \pi)^{3}}$. I'm not sure why that factor of V is there. I have come up with some explanations, the best of which is that the delta function $\delta^{(4)} (p_{F}-p_{I})$, due to considering only a finite space does not actually multiply by infinity, but by V. However, I need several factors of V, which I don't see how to get.
2. The next question is about the meaning of the probability he calculates. He gets a Probability which is something finite times a $t$, so that it grows infinitely in time. I don't get how does he then get from this the half life, as I don't even know how to make sense of a diverging probability like this (normalizing it in the normal way I know, would just give all the probability way at infinity).

So clearly, I must be missing some important things here.

Comment: Hi guillefix - you actually have two separate questions here. Would you mind editing out the second one (about the meaning of the probability) and putting it in a new post?

Comment: The second one is easy: its the linear term in the series $\exp(-\Gamma t)=1 - \Gamma t + \Gamma^2 t^2 /2 - \cdots$. You should review the derivation of Fermi's golden rule, as these technical details are very similar in that simpler context.

Comment: The content of this question would be clearer if the title were changed to something along the lines of: *Why multiply by volume when integrating over final momenta in scattering amplitude calculations?*

Comment: Michael, and how do I get the exponential from? (sorry for not finding it as easy..) The only place I see Tong has done an approximation is when evaluating $\int d E_{m} \rho (E_{m}) 2 |\langle m| H _{int} | n \rangle |^{2}  (\frac{1-cos(wt)}{w^{2}}) \rightarrow 2\pi t (E_{n}) |\langle m| H _{int} | n \rangle |^{2}$

And I don't see how that'd give an exponential, as it grows to infinity as $t \rightarrow \infty$, unlike the exponential.

Comment: Remember you are doing perturbation theory! The Golden Rule comes from a first-order approximation to the full time evolution operator. Approximations don't get much more approximate than that.

Comment: True I nearly forget that it's a leading order approximation. Still, taking into account the other terms in Dyson's formula, I don't see how you get the $\Gamma^{2} t^{2}/2$, etc.

Comment: Actually, I think it may work by saying that in a short time $dt$ you will loose a fraction $\Gamma dt$ of particles out of a population N, so that
$dN=-\Gamma dt$

Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

Typically in this kind of scattering calculation one works within a fictional finite volume as a regularisation technique, to ensure that your momentum states are normalisable. This is what Tong is doing here. In a finite box of volume $L^3$ with periodic boundary conditions, each component of the momentum of a plane-wave eigenstate can only take discrete values $p_{i} = \frac{2\pi n_i}{L}$, where $n_i$ is an integer. Therefore each state occupies a box of volume $(\frac{2\pi}{L})^3$ in momentum space.

In order to get the observable decay rate, one really needs to perform a *discrete sum* over final momentum states. However, this sum is much easier to perform by approximating it by an integral. (This approximation is good when $L$ is very large, so the momentum states are closely packed in $p$-space.) The momentum integral calculates the total *volume* in $p$-space occupied by the final states. What you really want is the *number* of final states within this total $p$-space volume. Therefore you must divide the integral by the volume occupied by each state:
$$ \sum\limits_{\mathbf{p}} \approx \frac{L^3}{(2\pi)^3}\int\mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{p}.$$
The factor $\frac{L^3}{(2\pi)^3}$ is also referred to as the **density of states** in $p$-space, for obvious reasons. Another way of seeing why this factor must be there is for dimensional consistency: the factor $L^3$ cancels the $[L]^{-3} $ dimension coming from the momentum integration.

About the second question, see the comment by Michael Brown below the OP's post. A first-order perturbation calculation based on the Golden Rule will only give the correct transition probability for short times. You cannot extrapolate transition probabilities thus calculated up to very long times, since higher order processes start to become important.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And just to check the delta function in the expression is then for when having a state which is a cluster of states with different 4-momentum, thus giving a factor of some $\rho(p_{I})$ ?

Comment: @guillefix Not sure I fully understand what you mean there. In first order perturbation theory a delta function will always appear enforcing energy(-momentum) conservation. There are many distinct final momenta satisfying this constraint, so you have to sum over all of them.

Comment: I mean that you don't want to have a delta function in a final answer, so you must do something like what he does when deriving Fermi's Golden Rule, where he gets a $\rho(E)$, don't you?

Comment: It looks like $\rho (E)$ in Tong's notation is the **density of states per unit energy**. I strongly advise you to go back to an elementary non-relativistic QM text and look up Fermi's Golden Rule there. Tong is not the place to be learning this stuff from.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for a book that would cover it well?

Comment: @guillefix The treatment in [Sakurai](http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Quantum-Mechanics-2nd-Edition/dp/0805382917) looks pretty good.